# Crashlytics installing - stuck on verifying installation step 2 of 2

Tags: ios, objective-c, crashlytics, twitter-fabric

I want to add Crashlytics to my project and I made everything according to Fabric Mac app and I now stuck at

> Step 2 of 2 when verifying installation

I've added:

```
[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];
```

to method:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
```

and I added imports too:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>
```

App is launched but in Fabric app there is still progress and nothing.

When I set debugMode to Yes I get these infos:

> 2016-07-13 11:23:21.689 Archimedes Cool[8565:3143059] [Crashlytics]
>   Version 3.7.2 (112) 2016-07-13 11:23:21.789 Archimedes
>   Cool[8565:3143059] [Crashlytics] Running on iPad4,4, 9.3.2 (13F69)
>   2016-07-13 11:23:21.883 Archimedes Cool[8565:3143059] [Fabric]
>   Initialized with kit versions: { "com.twitter.answers.ios" = "1.2.1";
>   "com.twitter.crashlytics.ios" = "3.7.2"; "io.fabric.sdk.ios" =
>   "1.6.7"; }
>
> 2016-07-13 11:23:22.555 Archimedes Cool[8565:3143092] [Fabric] failed
>   to download settings Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such
>   file or directory"
>   UserInfo={NSErrorFailingURLKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/cz.ai.Archimedes-Cool/settings?build_version=1.24.3.4537&display_version=1.24.3&instance=a5697790406418f18d7057545ad7cf5cc23e431d&icon_hash=db9967486042bc2829965401b58f06c932384acd&source=1,
>   NSErrorFailingURLStringKey=https://settings.crashlytics.com/spi/v2/platforms/ios/apps/cz.ai.Archimedes-Cool/settings?build_version=1.24.3.4537&display_version=1.24.3&instance=a5697790406418f18d7057545ad7cf5cc23e431d&icon_hash=db9967486042bc2829965401b58f06c932384acd&source=1}

I've tried it with real devices (iPad and iPhone) but not in simulator. I even tried to install it via CocoaPods but same problem. Can anyone help me? Thanks

Comment: after the Fabric initializiation, do you edit in any way the app temp directory?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think not. Just made steps by Fabric app. Where is app temp directory?

Comment: I found [this answer](https://twittercommunity.com/t/daily-new-users-tanked/62696) that has your same problem: `Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"`, after you call `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` are you doing anything else in your `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions`?

Comment: Yes, I have many other frameworks inits there.

Comment: It's possible that one of them is editing or deleting the data stored in the temp directory causing Fabric to fail the initialization. Can you try to put `[Fabric with:@[[Crashlytics class]]];` in the end of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and check if you still get the error?

Comment: That's it. If you set it as answer then I can accept it :) Thanks for help

Comment: No problem, Glad I could help! :)

Comment: I see this file in NSTemporaryDirectory() after Fabric starts up: CFNetworkDownload_rv7L7u.tmp Deleting it causes the 'No Such File or Directory' error to appear and Fabric to fail.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From [this answer](https://twittercommunity.com/t/daily-new-users-tanked/62696/17):

> this appears to happen when there is a method being called after the
>   Fabric init that is removing the temp directory of the app.This can
>   result in a race condition where new data is being written for other
>   Answers events, but new sessions are not recorded properly.

Move the `Fabric` initialization in the end of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in order to avoid other methods to override or delete the app's temp directory